# Add trace in plotly if a condition is met

Tags: r, plotly, mapbox

I'm creating a map with plotly which represents the tracks of some ships made at different points around Europe. For this I'm creating lines between the coordinates of my dataset so the way navigated by the different vessels are represented. However, as I have all vessels and their coordinates in the same dataset, the map also plots a line between campaigns of each vessel, without differentiating between one and another:

[image]

For it to differentiate I thought to create an ifelse statement, in which if the latitude coordinates between one row and the next one on my dataset vary by more than 1 point (which likely means we're talking about different vessels) then no line is drawn. This is where I get stuck.

Any ideas on how to not initially draw those lines or how to remove them from the inital plot?

Code:

```
#How I got the initial map
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

list_of_files <- list.files(path = "C:\\Users\\jesus.alonso.guerra\\Documents\\coordmap\\CoordMap\\ClayT",
                            recursive = TRUE,
                            pattern = "*.NAV",
                            full.names = TRUE)


colnames(df) <- c("vessel", "number", "Longitude", "Latitude", "date", "time")

C <- subset(df, number == 1| lead(number == 1))



Tracksmed2 <- C

fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scattermapbox',
  mode = "markers+lines",
  lon = Tracksmed2$Longitude,
  lat = Tracksmed2$Latitude,
  text = ~paste("Vessel :", Tracksmed2$vessel,
                "date :", Tracksmed2$date,
                "time :", Tracksmed2$time),
  marker = list(size = 10)) 


fig <- fig %>%
  layout(
    mapbox = list(
      style = "stamen-terrain",
      center = list(lon = 7.5, lat= 39.5),
      zoom = 5),
    margin =list(l=0,t=0,b=0,r=0))

fig

#And what I'm trying 
p <- plot_ly (type = 'scattermapbox',
              mode = "markers+lines",
              lon = Tracksmed2$Longitude,
              lat = Tracksmed2$Latitude)


#build it up
for(i in levels(factor(C$NewCol.Longitude))){
  #subset data
  dataFilt <- C[C$NewCol.Longitude=="no",]
  #add it
  p <- add_trace(type = 'scattermapbox',
                 mode = "markers+lines",
                 lon = Tracksmed2$Longitude,
                 lat = Tracksmed2$Latitude,
                 text = ~paste("Vessel :", Tracksmed2$vessel,
                               "date :", Tracksmed2$date,
                               "time :", Tracksmed2$time),
                 )
```

Screenshot of my data:
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.